# How to remove\replace big bracket while printing List or array in groovy?

Tags: collections, groovy

I have to give list of values into ***in*** clause of ***SQL query*** but while retrieving the values **[ ]** also come along with data which is **not readable** by query language.

For example I have list as:

```
def val = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

while doing `println(val)` output come as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` but in the query it is needed as: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8`

In java this one works as `System.out.println(val.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""))` but not in groovy. Can't we use collection to remove like this?

Comment: going toString -> replace -> SQL is most likely the wrong way to go.  why do you bang strings together instead of using e.g. prepared statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of:

```
def val = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

use:

```
def val = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)).join(', ')
```

or simply:

```
def val = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].join(', ')
```

Comment: Cann't we do using replaceAll()?

Comment: Doing this with `join` is much more groovier and less error prone.

Answer (score 2):

Try using g-strings and the minus operator:

```
println "${val}" - '[' - ']'
```